# How can i share codes on my blog?

Tags: shortcode, code

I want to add `<code>` tag to my post, easily. For example, Adding code is very easily in Stackoverflow and other sites. Basically, we can add codes between apostrophes (``) I need something like that for Wordpress .

Maybe i can use shortcode function for this.

For example :
`[code="<b>Hello</b>"]` will show exactly like this : `<b>Hello</b>`

In summary, i'm sharing a lot of HTML and PHP codes with my readers on my blog. I need an easily way to share them. Is it possible, like stackoverflow's apostrophe method ? Or maybe shortcodes ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using [Syntax Highlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/). It's by Viper007Bond. You can use it like this:

```
[sourcecode lang="php"]
<?php
echo 'Hello World!';
?>
[/sourcecode]
```

Or even like this:

```
[php]
<?php
echo 'Hello World!';
?>
[/php]
```

A screenshot:

[image]

### EDIT

An example of how you could do the backticks method that SE uses:

```
function wpse13653_content( $content ){
  return preg_replace( '@`([^`]+)`@', '<code>$1</code>', $content );
}

foreach( array( 'the_content', 'comment_text' ) as $hook )
  add_filter( $hook, 'wpse13653_content', 1 );

function wpse13653_excerpt( $content ){
  $content = preg_replace( '@`([^`]+)`@', '<code>$1</code>', $content );
  return str_replace( '`', '', $content );
}

add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpse13653_excerpt', 1 );
```

This would let you use backticks in comments and post text, but would also prevent the backticks from showing up in excerpts after the code's been stripped in automatic excerpts.

Comment: You misunderstood me, i'm recently using a plugin like this, but i don't want to use it just a `<br>` code for example. Actually, problem solved, i wrote a shortcode for me :)

Comment: now showing codes like this --> `&lt;!&#8211; &#8211;&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

OK, i'm using this :

```
function codefunc( $atts ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'c' => ''
), $atts ) );

return "<code>".htmlentities($c)."</code>";
}
add_shortcode( 'code', 'codefunc' );
```

Usage :

```
[code c="<br><b>Hello</b>"]
```

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest you use the `$content` argument instead of passing the code as an argument. e.g. `function codefunc( $atts, $content ){ return "<code>$content</code>"; }`. Usage would be like this: `[code]<br><b>Hello</b>[/code]`. Doing it that way would allow you to use both kinds of quotes without needing to escape them.

Comment: Hello, John, thanks! You mean this function? : http://pastebin.com/CdbPRACA

Comment: I think this is OK : `function codefunc( $atts, $content ) {

 return "<code>".htmlentities($content)."</code>";
}`

Comment: That last one looks great. You shouldn't need the `shortcode_atts` function anymore, though, since you're not using the attributes. Upvoted!

Comment: @Jonh, so i can't you apostrophes method of stackoverflow, right ?

Comment: You could, but you'd have to add a filter to `'the_content'` and `'the_excerpt'` on priority 9 or lower and run some sort of `preg_replace[_callback]` type function to handle the code swap. I'll edit my answer with an example.